# Accessing values in nested dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, key

I am trying to write a function that:

1. Counts the number of "sub-keys" of a key (e.g. 'e' is a sub-key of 'M')
2. Divides each sub-key's probability by the total number of sub-keys for that key
3. Modifies the numbers in place.

My function has to return **None**, however.
For example, if I had the dictionary:

```
defaultdict(dict, {'M': {'e': 1.0}, 'O': {'n': 2, 'x': 1.0}, 'I': {'_': 1.0, 's': 1}, 'P': {'t': 3}, 'L': {'ne': 1, 'n': 1.0}})
```

So for the example dictionary the converted dictionary output would be:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'M': {'e': 1.0}, 'O': {'n': 0.6666666666666666, 'x': 0.3333333333333333}, 'I': {'_': 0.5, 's': 0.5}, 'P': {'t': 1.0}, 'L': {'ne': 0.5, 'n': 0.5}})
```

Another example, if I had the dictionary:

```
defaultdict(dict, {('H', 't'): {'m': 2}, ('M', 'o'): {'ce': 1, 'p': 2}, ('K', '^'): {'d': 2}, ('F', 'x'): {'_': 1, 'g': 3}, ('J', 'o'): {'y': 1}, ('A', 'b'): {'k': 3}, ('X', '_'): {'r': 1}, ('N', 'e'): {'x': 1}})
```

The converted dictionary would be:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {('M', 'o'): {'ce': 0.3333333333333333, 'p': 0.6666666666666666}, ('K', '^'): {'d': 1.0}, ('F', 'x'): {'g': 0.75, '_': 0.25}, ('J', 'o'): {'y': 1.0}, ('H', 't'): {'m': 1.0}, ('A', 'b'): {'k': 1.0}, ('X', '_'): {'r': 1.0}, ('N', 'e'): {'l': 1.0}})
```

How would I go about doing this? How do I access keys within a defaultdict of dictionaries. What I am currently thinking is:

```
for major_key in dictionary:
    dictionary[major_key]...
```

...and that's where I get stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from being able to iterate over just the keys in dictionaries, in Python you can also iterate over key-value tuples , or just values. So we could do something like this:

```
for major_key, sub_dict in d.items():
    total_key_count = 0

    # Add up all sub key values to calculate probabilities
    for sub_count in sub_dict.values():
        total_key_count += sub_count

    # Now update nested dictionary values accordingly
    for minor_key, sub_count in sub_dict.items():
        sub_dict[minor_key] = sub_count / total_key_count
```

That should help give you the results you want. Note in Python 2 you should call `iteritems()` instead of `items()`, since in Python 2 `items()` actually builds a list of tupes, rather than returning an iterator like `iteritems()` does. Same with `values()` and `itervalues()`.